# Why an ionic modal freezes the UI when it is closed or submitted?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a popover which two options -Add Favorite and Add Comment-, the first options is working correctly: it does not freeze the user interface; but the second one once the form is omitted or submitted freezes the interface. This is what is happening:

[image: Android app]

Note how when I close the form the interface does not respond.

This is the code I have used to create the popover and and modal:

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/dish-detail-popover.html',{
scope: $scope}) 
.then(function(popover){
    $scope.popover = popover;
});

$scope.openPopover = function($event){
    $scope.popover.show($event);
}

$scope.closePopover = function() {
    $scope.popover.hide();
}; 

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/dish-comment.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.commentModal = modal;
});

// Triggered in the reserve modal to close it
$scope.closeAddComment = function() {
    $scope.commentModal.hide();
};

// Open the reserve modal
$scope.showCommentModal = function($event) {
    $scope.closePopover();
    $scope.commentModal.show($event);
};
```

The template for `dish-detail-popover.html`:

```
<ion-popover-view>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <a class="item" ng-click="addFavorite(dish.id)">
          Add to favorites
        </a>
        <a class="item" ng-click="showCommentModal()">
          Add Comment
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-popover-view>
```

and the template for `dish-comment.html`:

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Submit Comment on Dish</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeAddComment()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form id="comentDishForm" name="comentDishForm" ng-submit="doComment()">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
          <span class="input-label">Rating</span>
            <select ng-model="comment.rating">
                <option ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4,5]" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Your Name</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="comment.author">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Your Comment</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="comment.comment">
        </label>
        <label class="item">
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

**NOTE**: When the form is called from the Add Comment button (the green one), it works correctly. The failure is related when it called from the popover.

Some suggestions, or ideas,... to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The screen gets freezed because despite closing the popover before opening the modal, the body tag remains dirty with the class 'popover-open'. A quick solution, but not the neatest, is to close the popover again when closing the modal. This way, ionic framework will remove the class 'popover-open' from the body tag. Example:

```
$scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    $scope.closePopover();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the browser version it works correctly... but in the mobile version it doesn't.

Comment: Try to debug from chrome (url  chrome://inspect/), inspect the DOM and check if the class 'popover-open' has being removed when closing the popover. If not, you know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same issue and had no idea why this was happening. Reading the Ionic docs about `ionicPopover`, I found that the `.hide()` method is actually returning a promise which will resolve once the popover is animated out. So, what you can actually do is setup your `closePopover()` method as follows:

```
$scope.closePopover = function () {
    return $scope.popover.hide();
};
```

As for the method to be executed when someone clicks the "Add Comment" option, you can implement that as follows:

```
$scope.addComment = function addComment() {
    $scope.closePopover()
      .then(function() {
        $scope.openAddCommentModal();
      });
};
```

This will ensure that the modal is only shown once the popover is completely animated out and those classes are removed from the `body` tag. This will clear the dirty states and make the app respond.